# Testing Android real-time multiplayer game with only one physical device

Tags: java, android, real-time, multiplayer

I'm developing a real-time multiplayer game Android using the Google Play Services SDK.

Because of my lack of any proper budget, I want to be able to test the game with only one physical device.

My initial thought was, to run an AVD emulator with the Google APIs enabled. However, the problem I encountered was that the installed Google Play Services on the emulator was out of date, and couldn't be updated.

Since I doubt running two clients on a physical device would be the best alternative, perhaps **Can I connect a physical device with an AVD with outdated Google Play Services?** would be a more appropriate question - thought, the context is, I really want to test a real-time multiplayer game with only one physical device at disposal.

My Google Play Services version is `8298000`

Comment: Y dont you try Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing newest Android SDK with Google API's.
The newest once is

```
Android Marshmallow 6.0 (Google API's)
```

Better install. Compatibility.
(Sorry for my English, I'm from Poland)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although that have previously proved come with an outdated Google Play Services version than what apparently is required for my app.

Comment: Oh... Do you have Google Play Store? If yes, update Google Play Services, and all needed Google Play Apps (like Google Play Games).

Comment: From my experience I don't believe Google Play Store is available on the emulator.. even tried installing Play Services via adb and an .apk, though I got an error message saying the "Google Play Store wasn't enabled nor updated" on the emulator :(

Comment: Try using Genymotion, then download specified Google Play API's for your Android version. When downloaded Google Play API's flashable ZIP, drag it into your Genymotion emulator window. Then install it from popup window, after being installed reboot your Genymotion emulator. Worked for me.